# I want to configuration of same IP at source and different destination in Ubuntu, without switch

Tags: linux

[image: example figures]

Hi. I need to configure it as shown in Figure 2 in a dual LAN computer environment. Bonding deals with the case shown in Figure 1. How do I configure the case described in Figure 2?

I usually use a switch for the case shown in Figure 2, but I want to implement it without a switch. In the figure, the blue square box is the port of the LAN card.

Comment: I am not sure IP protocol would allow this.

Comment: How do you do the bonding as is for Figure 1? Would a simple bridge, and configuring the .1 IP directly on your bridge solve the problem? The bridge would act as a "virtual switch" in that case.

Answer (score 2):

In Figure 2, the way you've cabled your computer1 makes it actually a two-port switch. A two-port switch is commonly called a 'bridge'. You can create a bridge on the computer1 with the following commands:

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev br0 up
ip address add 192.168.1.1/24 dev br0

ip link set dev eth0 master br0
ip link set dev eth0 up

ip link set dev eth1 master br0
ip link set dev eth1 up
```

Read the documentation for your linux distro to make these settings permanent.
In the debian the settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` will look like:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Also, there is the more complicated way to implement what you want - usage of the unnumbered interface, the static routing and the arp-proxy.